# JqGrid fires 'aftersavefunc' & 'successfunc' before 'saveRow'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm trying to reload the grid after saving a row to be able to get the Id of the row for logging purposes but somehow 'aftersavefunc' and 'successfunc' fires 'reloadGrid('#telephoneGrid')' before saving. It seems that 'aftersavefunc' and 'successfunc' is identical. Now I can't add nor edit any row.

```
    var lastSel;

    function onTelephoneSelect(id, status, e) {

        if ($(e.target).hasClass('edit')) {
            var editParameters = getEditParameters();
            if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                jQuery('#telephoneGrid').saveRow(lastSel);
            }
            jQuery("#telephoneGrid").jqGrid('editRow', id, editParameters);
            lastSel = id;
        }
    }

    function getEditParameters() {
        return {
            "keys": true,
            "oneditfunc": null,
            "successfunc": null,
            "url": '@Url.Action("SaveTelephoneEntry","TelephoneEntry")?customerId=' + $('#SelectCompany').val(),
            "extraparam": {},
            "aftersavefunc": reloadGrid('#telephoneGrid'),
            "errorfunc": null,
            "afterrestorefunc": null,
            "restoreAfterError": true,
            "mtype": "POST"
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty desperate now and couldn't figure out any working solution.

Could someone please assist me here or has already faced the same issue and figured out a working solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, please include always the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Seconds, the usage of `aftersavefunc` is correct, but I suppose that you could have a problem in the implementation of `reloadGrid` function. Do you use `setTimeout` inside? What exactly work incorrect now? Do you see *old data* after reloading? Which `datatype` has the grid? Do you use `loadonce: true` option?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Oleg. I'll keep in mind posting the version and fork I use in the future. 

Below the poster called Jay had the proper answer which worked for me. Everything ('aftersavefunc', 'successfunc') works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'aftersavefunc' and 'successfunc' are callbacks but it appears you're trying to set the function directly, so they're getting called before you intend.

Using the proper callback signature it should look something like this:

```
"aftersavefunc": function (rowid, response, options) {
    reloadGrid('#telephoneGrid');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need getter for *EditParameters* (instead of just defining the object and using it directly), but have you checked the values for *editParameters* whether they get set properly, just before firing:

```
 jQuery("#telephoneGrid").jqGrid('editRow', id, editParameters);
```

Your getter is inside `.hasClass('edit')` so you might try to use your getter before going to edit-sub, right after `function onTelephoneSelect(id, status, e) {` To see if it makes any difference. (Just because we do not know where/when you call *onTelephoneSelect*).

Comment: I need the _EditParameters_ twice. Once for adding a new entry (not mentioned in the question) and for editing. 

Unfortunately it makes no difference. _onTelephoneSelect_ gets called when edit-icon gets clicked and the grid should only reload after successful saving.

Comment: Why do you assume the saving happens "before" 'aftersavefunc' is fired? It would seem to me that "jQuery('#telephoneGrid').saveRow(lastSel);
" is inside IF block and it will fire aftersavefunc inside that block AFTER save (as it should?) and then you run "jQuery("#telephoneGrid").jqGrid('editRow', id, editParameters);
" outside the block - AFTER the save? In which case it would be logical to expect reloadGrid happens before your query for ID?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should've wrapped the 'aftersavefunc'.